# i cant delete the specific column data by Timestamp

Tags: hbase, hbase-shell

I am trying to delete specific column data by its `Timestamp`, but getting error.

```
delete 'Blog', 'Michelle-004', 'info:date', 2024-02-26T20:29:31.125
```

> syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT) delete 'Blog', 'Michelle-004',
> 'info:date', 2024-02-26T20:29:31.125

error in timestamp = 2024-02-26T20:29:31.125
^

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **correct syntax** for the `timestamp` format. The `timestamp` should be enclosed in **single quotes** and follow the proper format.

```
delete 'Blog', 'Michelle-004', 'info:date', '2024-02-26T20:29:31.125'
```

Or you can convert the Timestamp to milliseconds then execute the command:

```
delete 'Blog', 'Michelle-004', 'info:date', 1645885771125
```

Comment: ERROR: no constructor for arguments